# Video Streaming to a client app using Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming, asp.net-web-api

I have to write an ASP.NET Web API to retrieve a video or audio file from the server directory and stream it to a client app. I am totally a novice in the streaming area, i wanted to know if the server needs any infrastructure for it? If not then can anyone direct me towards some samples or can provide me with some code to start with? I haven't been able to find any information about it at all.

Thanks

Comment: you could probably do worse than start here: http://www.iis.net/media

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement video streaming directly in your ASP.NET Web API project almost without special configuration of IIS.

Check this example how to handle with straming in Web API
http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/archive/2012/12/12/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx

Also read this article for some useful details of IIS configuration and utilization for streaming.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/